# html5 - drag and drop - not trigger a drop event

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

Here is the js fiddle. 
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fSA4N/6/)

doesn't seem to trigger the drop event. Any insight..

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're forgetting to add a `preventDefault()` to the `onDragOver` event within your dropzone. A lot of these HTML5 events interfere with the way that the browsers normally do things, so you have to clear the defaults before triggering them.

```
<div id="div" ondragover="event.preventDefault()">Drop here</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LuMCs/1/